# how to get the DIV ID from given HTML in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have below HTML format:

```
<ul class="whatlike-list">
    <li class="first">
        <a href="/SessionHandler.aspx" class="button-flight-search">Search for Flights</a>
        <div class="open-block-holder">
            <div id="slideFlightSearch" class="open-block" style="display: block; left: 650px;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I am looking to get DIV ID="**slideFlightSearch**" on the click of link **"Search for Flights"**, I have got the class "button-flight-search" in my $this object. Something like below in my JQuery.

```
$(link).click(function()
{
    alert($(this).attr("class"));
})
```

In the above alert I am getting the class "button-flight-search", however I need the inner DIV ID slideFlightSearch

Please suggest using JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), like this:

```
$(link).click(function() {
    var id = $(this).next(".open-block-holder")
                    .find("div") // or .find("div.open-block")
                    .attr("id");
});
```

Comment: Isn't the question about getting to `#slideFlightSearch` w/o knowing the ID? If we know the id, we could just skip immediately to `$('#slideFlightSearch').doSomething();`

Comment: No I need just the div ID, which will be passed in my code for furthur use

Comment: @David Hedlund - Thank you for the input. Fixed.

Comment: @thanks Karim, What if there are more inhereted DIVs, there can be many other DIVs under DIV slideFlightSearch, I just need to be more accurate

Comment: @MKS: Depending on your structure, you could add `.find('div:first')` to only get the first `div` (or any other way that gives you the first only).

Comment: `.attr('id')` will always just yield the ID of the first element in the set, regardless of whether there were more that were matched by the selector...

Comment: ...or you could do `.find("div")[0].id`, but @David Hedlund is right about `.find`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$('a').click(
    function(){
        var theDivID = $(this).closest('li').find('.open-block').attr('id');
        alert('The div's ID is: ' + theDivID);
        return false; // If you need to prevent the default action of clicking on a link.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A method using your HTML structure without using ID or class attributes.

```
$(link).click(function()
{
    alert($(this).next()         //get div with class "open-block-holder".
                 .children()     //get the inner div with class "open-block".
                 .attr("id") ) ; //get the ID.

})
```